# Infinite Zoom Blender

Tags: rendering, camera

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gtvROMb59WXV3SZNH1_DZnJhHFueWp4C 
  I need a smooth infinite zoom like this
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_UxbldMl9jNphuOYLkA9DFLwCH8obNOE 
  But here is mine, it looks very dirty and doesn't quite fit right, any idea how can I fix this?
- I need the camera to infinite zoom in to a city road.
  What I do is render out tele/medium and wide-angle so that's 3 shots from one camera and then change the camera and make another doing the same approach, in the end I parent them up and just play with the scale to get the effect, but how do I fix them together when I have to like go forward the first camera renders doesn't fix with the second.

Comment: Way better formatting.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.